# How to catch query param changes with Backbone.Router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone.Route:

```
var CustomRoute = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/search": "onChangeUrl"
    },

    onChangeUrl: function (query, page) {
        // handle event
    }
});

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

And the following url: `http://www.mysite_.com/search?name=erik&age=34`

How could I handle event on changing any query params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define two routers, like so

```
var CustomRoute = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      'search': 'onChangeUrl',
      'search?*query': 'onChangeUrl'
    },

    onChangeUrl: function (query) {
        // handle event
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WSX5E/42/)